# iOS DropboxSDK [WARNING] - ( 400 )

Tags: ios, dropbox

I demo the sample code "DBRoulette",and use my Appkey and Appsecret to run, Access type = App folder,but when i build to run picture then show this warning , please give me some instruction to this warning than show the picture,thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to [DropBox Api (Standard API errors)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api)

400 Bad input parameter. Error message should indicate which one and why.

You can further investigate error object for details!

Comment: Next day when I try this semple than it can work , I do not have to modify any code , what's wrong with it.

Comment: @AliceChen sad but sometimes the dropbox servers go down, this may also cause this!